# Convert C# logic to powershell for TFS

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a C# program which build me a TFS build definition. I want to do the same code in a powershell script. So far, I have been able code the script which will create me a new build definition in TFS. However, I have trouble setting Process section of the build definition. I need to convert the below code in C# to powershell and all attemps I have made did not work.

```
//Set process parameters 
var process = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters);
//Set BuildSettings properties 
BuildSettings settings = new BuildSettings();
settings.ProjectsToBuild = new StringList("$/Templates/Main/Service/application1"); 
settings.PlatformConfigurations = new PlatformConfigurationList(); 
settings.PlatformConfigurations.Add(new PlatformConfiguration("Any CPU", "Debug"));
process.Add("BuildSettings", settings);

buildDefinition.ProcessParameters = WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(process);
```

First I loaded the assemblies I need to work with TFS. When I want to replicate the same C# code as,

```
var process = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters);
```

I did following in PowerShell

```
$process = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.
```

Above gave me an error saying "Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers"

I checked and there are no constructors for that. My question is what I am I doing wrong in writing the PowerShell script to achieve the same functionality as c# code. I am sure it's syntax error that I am doing and not aware of the correct way of doing it in PowerShell.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Yes I should have asked the question with what I did and what the error I got. I have edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear from your code snippet (and confirmed via [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.workflowhelpers.deserializeprocessparameters.aspx)) that the `DeserializeProcessParameters` is a static method on the `WorkflowHelpers` class. You would need to invoke it with the following syntax in PowerShell:

```
$process = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::DeserializeProcessParameters($buildDefinition.ProcessParameters)
```

It looks like the buildDefinition variable is declared earlier - so I just stuck a $ character on it to make it a legit PowerShell variable. Same thing with the process variable. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know the syntax in PowerShell to invoke it. I declared the buildDefinition variable earlier. I was able to run the process by using your Syntax.