# PowerShell Syntax Error

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I am working on a powershell script that will create TFS build definitions. I have used below example as my starting point.

http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/04/26/creating-a-build-definition-using-the-tfs-2010-api.aspx

I have the script done in powershell and it creates me a build definition file in TFS. One thing I am stuck in is creating Process information such as "Item to build" and "Projects to build". The C# code for this is given below

```
//Set process parameters 
varprocess = WorkflowHelpers.DeserializeProcessParameters(buildDefinition.ProcessParameters); 

//Set BuildSettings properties 
BuildSettings settings = newBuildSettings(); 
settings.ProjectsToBuild = newStringList("$/pathToProject/project.sln"); 
settings.PlatformConfigurations = newPlatformConfigurationList(); 
settings.PlatformConfigurations.Add(newPlatformConfiguration("Any CPU", "Debug")); 
process.Add("BuildSettings", settings); 

buildDefinition.ProcessParameters = WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(process);
```

Below is the powershell code I have written to achive above.

```
Write-Host"Set process parameters "$now
$process=[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::DeserializeProcessParameters($def.ProcessParameters)
Write-Host"Set build settings properties "$now
$settings=new-object-`enter code here`TypeNameMicrosoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings
$sList=New-Object-TypeNameMicrosoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.StringList
$sList="$/pathToProject/project.sln"
$settings.ProjectsToBuild =$sList
$process.Add("BuildSettings", $sList)
```

But the above segment of code does not create me the Build settings in my build definition file. Myquestion is am I doing this the correct way in powershell? I feel I am not writing the powershell code incorrectly as I am newbie to powershell. Any guidance and
help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you get any errors and/or output?

Comment: i only indicated the code that I have the problem in the question. When I run the full script, it creates me the build definition file. But the Process information such as "Item to build" and "Projects to build" is empty and when executing, it does not throw any errors for me. I think, I might be writing the powershell syntax incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a constructor with parameters should be done like this in PowerShell:

```
$ns = 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities'
$settings.ProjectsToBuild = new-object "$ns.StringList" '$/pathToProject/project.sln'
```

Also note the use of single quotes around the TF server path.  `$` is s special character in PowerShell - tells it what follows is either a variable name or sub-expression even in a string.  Unless that string is single quoted.  In which case, PowerShell doesn't interpret any special characters within the string.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Been a novice I did not know how to call a constructor in powershell. Now I know how to do it and I was able to solve my problem.